# glBindTextures returns GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: opengl, bitmap, textures

here is some code

```
GLEnum gl_error;
CString sError = "";
gl_error = glGetError(); //clear the error code
glEnd(); // to make sure Im not between glBegin/glEnd pairing

GLuint tex1;
glGenTextures( 1, &tex1 );

gl_error = glGetError();
if(gl_error == GL_INVALID_VALUE){
    sError = "GL Gen Texture failed\r\n"; // << this does NOT get hit
}

glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex1 );

gl_error = glGetError();
switch(gl_error){
case GL_INVALID_VALUE:
    sError = "GL Bind Texture failed, VALUE\r\n";
    break;
case GL_INVALID_ENUM:
    sError = "GL Bind Texture failed, ENUM\r\n";
    break;
case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:
    sError = "GL Bind Texture failed, OPERATION\r\n"; // <<< this DOES get hit
    break;
}
```

"GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if texture has a dimensionality which
doesn't match that of target.

GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if glBindTexture is executed  between
the execution of glBegin and the corresponding execution of glEnd."

These are the causes of OPERATION error after glBindTexture(), or so I am told by many reference pages.
I call a glEnd() by itself to make sure I am out of glBegin()/glEnd() pairs.
So I must fall under the second error,,,my texture's dimensionality doesn't match that of the target, however I have been told these 2 functions are all that is needed to create(glGenTextures) a unique texture and bind it(glBindTexture).

ALSO:

```
GLuint tex1, tex2;
glGenTextures( 1, &tex1 );
glGenTextures( 1, &tex2 );
if(tex1 == tex2){
    sError = "GL Get Tecture failed\r\n";
}
```

I'm under the assumption that tex1 and tex2 should be unique. but they are not, could my creation of these texture names be my issue? These calls to glGenTexture do NOT return GL_INVALID_VALUE

Comment: What is the deal with the stray `glEnd (...)` call in the middle of nowhere? If that is indeed terminating a `glBegin (...)` call, then the call to `glGenTextures (...)` immediately before it is invalid.

Comment: One of the reasons a GL_INVALID_OPERATION is returned by glBindTexture is that glBindTexture must be called outside of a glBegin()/glEnd pair, So to make sure this was not my problem I placed a single glEnd() before my glBindTexture.

Comment: Your biggest problem, however, is that you are generating a texture name and storing it in `tex1`. Later on, you try to bind a texture named `m_texture` (which could be anything... a 1D, 3D, Cubemap, Rectangle, etc...) texture. If it is not the name of a 2D texture, then this error will occur.

Comment: @ andon: oh i will try placing the glEnd() before the glGenTextures() call.

edit: this did not solve the issue.

Comment: @andon: sorry, i was copying and pasting code, i assure you I am binding to the created texture name, and still getting this error.

Comment: How would I assign the tex1 to be a TEXTURE_2D? the first function where both these values appear is glBindTexure.

Comment: That is when the association occurs. `glGenTextures (...)` does not create a texture, it just returns the first unused name it finds. The texture is created (and thus given a type, such as `GL_TEXTURE_2D`) the very first time you bind it. From that point on, it is an error to bind it to any other target.

Comment: as you can see, this texture is new, freshly given a value by glGenTexture, and then Bound to a texture_2d type. Which I think we can both agree on is the correct way, however I am getting the OPERATION error, upon this first bind.

Comment: Did you call `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`?

Comment: @user111: no i did not. where should i place this? right before my call to glGenTexture(),,,and when should I call glDisable()?

Comment: You'll want to enable it before binding, and disable it after you're done using that texture target. Usually after drawing with it. I tend to use `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);` at the end followed by `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`. That tells GL to bind nothing to the texture 2D target, and then to disable the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to run this code before even running my main() function, So all my OpenGL initialization calls had not been run yet.

I could have sworn I tried this in the past, but I definitely have more errors, that could have caused it not to run back then either.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue, glBindTexture() didn't work.

I managed to fix it setting texture parameters prior to glTexImage2D()

```
glGenTextures(1, &texOGL);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texOGL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
```